# Volley Error 500

Tags: android, api, url, android-volley

I am trying to parse a [url](http://www.mytransport.sg/content/mytransport/home/myconcierge/trafficcameras/jcr:content/par/cameras_slideshow.singleresult.html?cameraid=2704) that i found online.

However when i try to use `Volley` standard way of sending a request, it keeps giving me the error of

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://www.mytransport.sg/content/mytransport/home/myconcierge/trafficcameras/jcr:content/par/cameras_slideshow.singleresult.html?cameraid=2704
```

However, when i try to access the `url` via my google chrome, it works fine without any problem.

This is my code:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.e("RESPONSE", response);


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            // Error handling
            error.printStackTrace();

        }
    });

    // Add the request to the queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: That error messages makes it look like your url string is empty.

Comment: @DougStevenson just edited. The url string is not empty.